# React leave a message component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if this is not a SO question, I searched on google and couldn't find any answers.

Does anyone know where can I find a "leave a message" component for React?

I'm talking about a bubble/image at the bottom of the page and when the user clicks on it, it open a text field for the user to insert a message.

Once the user clicks on submit, it will send me the message through an email.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Agreed to the above comment. What we can help you with is if you try implement it yourself and get stuck along the way. In that case, come back and post what you have tried and what doesn't work and I'm sure someone will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

this is a back-end process and you must make a `fetch` post request to a link like this : `https://email-link-needs-user-email` and send user `email` and `message` to this API link

and you must use `axios` or `fetch` for it :

these links might help you :

1.[how to fetch in react](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/)

2.[how to use axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Hey, I'm not talking about the BE, only the FE. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel here...

Answer (score 0):

There is two tasks in your request.

1. Create component
2. Send a message via email

1) Task you can easily solve using react like way (conditional rendering). For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class MessageBox extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                image: '/path_to_image',
                showBox: false
            }
        }

    replaceImage = () => {
        this.setState(() => { return { showBox: true }})
    }

    render () {
        return this.state.showBox ? <textarea></textarea> :
            <img src={this.state.image} onClick={this.replaceImage()} />
        }
    }

export default MessageBox
```

2) This is the mission for server. You should create async request from your application to your rest server (XHR, fetch e.t.c) and send email via PHP or Python.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksander :) I was looking for something with a bit more style. Something like zendesk for example.